# Can't get subroutine info for specified shader type

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am using separated shader objects programs and now trying to integrate subroutines.

I acquire subroutine indices using  glGetSubroutineIndex() .Then I set current subroutine with :

```
glUniformSubroutinesuiv(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,1,&( _subrotines.find(method)->second));
```

I am getting the following OpenGL error message:

> "ID:1282 , SEVERITY:HIGH , Message: GL_INVALID_OPERATION error
>   generated.Could note get subroutine info for the specified shader
>   type. "

Here is how I define the subroutines in the fragment shader:

```
subroutine vec4 RenderMode();
subroutine uniform RenderMode renderMode;

subroutine (RenderMode)
vec4 lightsMode(){

    // returns some color 
}
  subroutine (RenderMode)
vec4 colorMode(){

    // returns some color 
}

void main(void){

   vec4 fragout =renderMode();
   OUTPUT=  fragout;
}
```

It did work ok when I used regular shader programs but doesn't seem to work with the separate.

Comment: What error do you get if you bind 0 with `glBindProgramPipeline` before calling `glUniformSubroutines`? You should still get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error, but I'm trying to see what the text of the error will be when you change it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your shader program in use before selecting a subroutine with `glUniformSubroutinesuiv()`. The steps would be:

```
glUseProgram(program);
glUniformSubroutinesuiv(...);
glUseProgram(0);
```

Keep in mind that *unusing* your program will reset your subroutine selection. So you will have to call `glUniformSubroutinesuiv()` again.

Comment: You mean it will reset when used with separate programs or with the regular programs as well?

Comment: It'll reset your subroutine selection for a GLSL program that contains subroutines (assuming this is what you mean by separate programs). There's nothing to reset for GLSL programs without subroutines.